# what kind of item is most important for IDE

Tags: javascript, html, function, ide

As we all know HTML5 games is very fast and easy to develop,but there will also be many problems.
What trouble you when developing HTML5 games? A function to realize?Project management?I list some choices, would you like to share what is your pain?
I would like to make a tool to help you solve it!

For Project Management
1.Version control
2.Source management
3.Code management
4.Others (Please list them!)  _____

For Function Modules
1.Plug-in (spine,texturepacker,tiled,or other plug-ins)
2.Animation
3.collision module
4.Physics engine
5.Game publish
6.how to make money?ads SDK,payment SDK?And integrate them
7.others (Please list them!) _____

Let me know your opinion!Thanks!

Comment: This isn't an opinion forum nor a place for research polls

Comment: Just like a discussion

Comment: Call it whatever you want...question is not appropriate for this site per the site guidelines in help center